# change column name in pandas, which will be used to change name for 1 column

Tags: python, pandas

change column name in pandas, which will be used to change name for 1 column.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl.workbook import Workbook
df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\Desktop\testing.xlsx')
df.loc[((df.spin== 'sor') | (df.spin== r'f/r')), 'mtm' ] = df["mtm"] + df["wes"] *100000
df.rename(columns={'mtm':'mtm_new'}, inplace=True)
writer =pd.ExcelWriter(r'C:\Users\Desktop\output.xlsx')
df.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1')
writer.save()
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

```
df.loc[((df.SPIN == 'COR') | (df.SPIN == r'F/R')), 'MTM'] = (df["MARKET PRICE"] - df["TRADE PRICE"]) * (
df["QTY"] / 100)
df.rename(columns={'MTM': 'Market to Market'}, inplace=True)
reportName = "Output"
reportFileOut = rptDirPath + '\\' + reportName + '.xlsx'
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(reportFileOut)
df.to_excel(writer, 'Sheet1')
writer.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

df = pd.read_excel(reportFileOut)df.sort_values(by=['DOF'],inplace=True, ascending=False)writer = pd.ExcelWriter(reportFileOut)df.to_excel(writer, 'Sheet1')writer.save()

Answer (score -1):

df.loc[(df.SPIN == 'COR') | (df.SPIN == 'F/R')]
  df["MTM"] = (df["MARKET PRICE"] - df["TRADE PRICE"]) * (df["QTY"]/100)
this is actual formulla , please check- If spin = F/R or COR , MTM = ([MKT PRICE]-[trade price])*([qty]/100)

Answer (score -2):

```
df.loc[((df.SPIN == 'COR') | (df.SPIN == 'F/R')), 'MTM' = ((df["MARKET PRICE"] -
df["TRADE PRICE"]) * (df["QTY"]/100))
```

This is actual formulla , please check- If

```
spin = F/R or COR , MTM = ([MKT PRICE]-[trade price])*([qty]/100)
```